# big commerce hover menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu, e-commerce, accordion

Ok so I'm limited to how i can customize the menu in big commerce. This is what i have so far, keep in mind some tags are generated by the system it self.

the code for the panel that displays the category menu in an accordion looks like this:

```
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li')
    .hover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').children().slideDown()
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children('ul').children().slideUp()
    });
$('a[href*="-main"]').attr('href', '#')
```

there is also a inline style sheet as well

```
.SideCategoryListClassic ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
```

the way that the menu is generated is beyond me. one of the things i added was the HERF replacement tag, to disable the link on the main category and only have it work on sub categories.

now the menu functions as a hover, but i want it to be a click function menu. I want the group to extend on click, but if i click on another group, id like to hide the previous one. keep in mind i can't modify how the UL's are generated nor assign style classes or id tags to them. you can see how the menu look like now at this page:

http://www.d2industries.mybigcommerce.com/about-us/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').click(function(){
    $('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').not(this).children('ul').children().slideUp();
    $(this).children('ul').children().slideToggle()
});​
```

Use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to toggle the state of each menu when clicked.

First line selects all of the menus that are **not** this one and slides them up. Second line toggles the slide of the current menu. If you don't want the user to be able to close the currently open menu by clicking it again, change `slideToggle` to `slideUp`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tyVPs/)

Comment: that kind of worked, but still doesn't do what i need it to do. if you go to the page you will see when you click on "complete systems" than click on "management components" the "management components" will open and close right away, but if you click it again it will finally open. however the first menu does not hide back up. each main parent is identified with "-main" in the actually URL which I'm using to eliminate the link, so i don't know if that can somehow help with the ID'ing the proper menu. i could add numbers to each link to for the main category

Comment: I hadn't thought of that case, updated my answer with a better solution. Note, I am not able to test it as it conflicts with the existing code on your site.. so let me know.

Comment: now the menu completely hides when i open the page... this is what my whole script looks like

    $('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li')
    .slideToggle()(function()    {$(this).children('ul').children().slideDown()},
    function(){$(this).children('ul').children().slideUp()});
var rolledDown = false;
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').children().slideToggle()
});
    
    $('a[href*="-main"]').attr('href', '#')

Comment: ok i changed that, works now, but it does not hide the prior menu when clicking on the next one.