# How to disable parent category links in accordion menu

Tags: javascript, accordion, parent-child, href, bigcommerce

I am using a nice and simple accordion script (below) from [big commerce hover menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056808/big-commerce-hover-menu) on a Bigcommerce site http://cch-learning.mybigcommerce.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').click(function(){
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').not(this).children('ul').children().slideUp();
$(this).children('ul').children().slideToggle()
});
</script>
```

There is the simpleinline style sheet in use

```
.SideCategoryListClassic ul li ul li {
display: none;
}
```

Trouble is, the top-level parent categories are acting as links  - rather than triggering the slide-down to reveal the sub categories.

**Is there a tweak to the script that will remove the href links on all parent categories?**
Either that, or have a click-to-toggle followed by a click-to-link instruction?

Comment: add `return false;` to the end of that function.  Also you can just do `$(selector).removeAttr('href');` and it'll turn into plain text but still keep its tag.  I don't really know what selector you're aiming for here so I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks @Deryck almost there now. The original script has been tweaked to

`</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').click(function(){
$("li:only-of-type").removeAttr('href');
$('.SideCategoryListClassic').children().children('li').not(this).children('ul').children().slideUp();
$(this).children('ul').children().slideToggle()
return false;});
</script>`

But I think I've placed the `return false;` in the wrong place because the child dropdown links are removed as well.